# Can't install library(Xgboost) for gpu in R (Windows 10)

Tags: r, gpu

I want to install the xgboost package for R with GPU support for Win10

I downloaded the tarball using this link https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/releases/download/v1.6.0/xgboost_r_gpu_win64_1.6.0.tar.gz

I tried to manually install via the Rgui and I got this error

```
Warning in system("sh ./configure.win") : 'sh' not found
ERROR: configuration failed for package 'xgboost'
* removing 'C:/Users/adminos/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/xgboost'
Warning message:
In install.packages(files[tarballs], .libPaths()[1L], repos = NULL,  :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/adminos/Downloads/xgboost_r_gpu_win64_1.6.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

So non-zero exit status lib wasn't installed.
How can I install Xgboost for GPU?
Please Help

Comment: Do you have rtools installed? If you do, can you try running install packages this way: `install.packages(full_file_path, repos = NULL, type="source")`